# Is there an elegant way to wait for file exist in bash shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm aware of shell's file testing and while / until loop, which can be used, like:

```
while [ ! -f /path/file ]
do
  sleep 1.2
done
```

But it seems lengthy to me, what I'm looking for is something like this:

```
testUntilFileExist file && dosomething file
```

That is, a simple and concise command to keep checking if file exist, after it is created, then do something about it.
All done in a one-liner.
Mostly I'll do it inside the file path, so it should be able to ignore the path.

Is there an elegant way like that?
I can also use awk/sed/grep/etc., or install new GNU command if needed.
(Best if there's a way to use existing things, thus to avoid install new tool or implement new function on multiple servers.)

Comment: Would `test -f file && dosomething file` would address your use case?

Comment: BTW, why did you believe the while loop and the `sleep` command were necessary? they seem a bit "off-topic" for what you're asking.

Comment: Updated it a bit, I need it to keep testing/waiting until the file exist. @ErikMD

Comment: That is, usually the file doesn't exist, until another program created or uploaded it, then do things with it. @ErikMD

Comment: OK, makes sense. Will suggest something as an answer, maybe

Comment: Does it need to be **part of bash itself**? There are excellent solutions for this, but they're OS-dependent and not included in the shell.

Comment: ...see for example `inotifywait` on Linux (as well as the other components of `inotify-tools` kit, a set which includes `incron`)

Comment: Are you aware that the file might cease to exist after you tested it existed but before `dosomething` starts?

Comment: ...similarly, on MacOS, launchd can be set to run a service when filesystem events happen; on Linuxy systems new enough to have systemd, a path service can be created to trigger a script or other service to run whenever filesystem changes happen; etc. There are lots of good ways to do this that don't involve busy-waits, but none of them are actually _part of bash itself_.

Comment: Yeah I can install things if it can be used on bash shell and can be trusted :)  @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @Tiw, ...so, which operating system are you targeting?

Comment: That's unlikely to happen in my daily use, good point though, thanks for point out. :)  @choroba

Comment: (checking, the duplicate I'm closing this with _does_ have non-busywait answers).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well it's also the old way, or install the `inotifywait`. While install a new tool is also a way, I'm kinda also looking forward to a way to use things already inside linux shell, so it's a no go?

Comment: If it's just the syntax you are concerned with, and not the polling loop, you can just wrap it in a function: `testUntilFileExist () { while ! [ -f "$1" ]; do sleep 1.2; done; }`.

Comment: Well that can be done but not elegant imo, I'd like to have some conciseness at the expense of some cpu time and/or io. :)  @chepner

Comment: How is that not concise? You only have to define the function once. Just because it's not built-in to the shell doesn't mean your subsequent code that uses it isn't concise.

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that. I was looking for a simpler way though, kinda want to avoid install new things or implement a new function on every servers.  But maybe I'm asking too much.  @chepner

Comment: You are; the shell itself doesn't implement this, because there is no standard interface for it to leverage. Checking if a file exists is standard enough that any reasonable platform will provide a way for `bash` to do this. *Blocking* until a file exists is not; different operating systems have vastly different ways of doing this, if it's available at all, so `bash` doesn't try to bundle it.

Comment: I see. Guess I'll settle for the solutions I got for now. Thanks :)  @chepner